# How do I know if my HDD is connected to a USB 3.0 or 2.0?

Tags: usb, hard-drive

`lsusb` says:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 125f:a15a A-DATA Technology Co., Ltd. DashDrive Durable HD710 portable HDD various size
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If I'm not much mistaken, that means my A-DATA external hard drive is connected to Bus 001 which is USB 2.0 protocol, right? HDD Copy rate also suggests USB 2.0 connection:

[image: Copy rate]

I'm pretty sure that the host USB is a 3.0 (blue slot on back side of a ASUS H170-Pro). So why my Ubuntu does not recognize USB 3.0 PHY ?

Comment: `Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub` is your USB 3.0 device.  Anything that would be attached on Bus 002 would be connected to a USB 3.0 port

Comment: Check your UEFI settings for any USB options.